# Why is this not working? Does not execute code?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, autocomplete, sqldatareader

I am trying to have a textBox auto complete with values from a database. When i bullet test the code will walk though until the `if` statement in the function below. Could some one please tell me why my code wont execute after that `if`?

I am trying to run the following but it keeps jumping out before the `if`:

```
public AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoCompleate(string dataBase, string procedure)
{
        AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection =
            new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        SqlDataReader dReader;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // This is the last place my bullet check 
                                       // gets before it hop's out!
        if (dReader.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (dReader.Read())
                namesCollection.Add(dReader["SystemUser"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
        dReader.Close();
        return namesCollection;
    }
```

***Additional information, but please focus on the above!***

---

*Please ask if you need any info. :)*

---

**The Call to the above:**

```
textBoxUser.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBoxUser.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBoxUser.AutoCompleteCustomSource = 
    DatabaseService.Instance.AutoCompleate("AuditIT", "AutoCompleate");
```

**Stored Proc:**

```
USE [AuditIT]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--Allow textboxs to have a autocomplete
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[AutoCompleate] 
 as

 Select distinct SystemUser from SchemaAudit
             order by SystemUser asc
```

Comment: how do you define your `SqlConnection` `con`?

Comment: If it "jumps out" it means that an exception was thrown. Have you tried running the code in the debugger? Are you using an exception handler outside this code?

Comment: @AlexR.  con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString.ToString() ); the connection string works i have other functions done the same way :)

Comment: Another vote for running it through the debugger.  What is the specific exception being returned?

Comment: not seems right way for auto complete, why don't you cache the records and do the auto complete?

Comment: @alliswell Doing a search for DB items, what better way to do a search then to list available options :D

Comment: I have got it all sorted thanks i made a edit on Felice Pollano's answer once he accepts the edit his answer will be the right one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unhandled exception when you try to hit the database.
Try to refactor the code as this:

```
try{

if (dataBase.Length > 0) { procedure = dataBase + ".." + procedure; } //Set procedure to DBNAME..ProcedureName

SqlDataReader dReader;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // This is the last place my bullet check gets before it hop's out!
            if (dReader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (dReader.Read())
                    namesCollection.Add(dReader["SystemUser"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
            dReader.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // handle the exception better than me :)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Put a messagebox or a breakpoint on the console.WriteLine and see what's happen.